# Why does the Smithsonian have a replica of Alan Shepard's golf club, and the real one is at a golf museum?

Tags: reduced-gravity-sports, museum-exhibits, apollo-14

Alan Shepard famously hit two [golf balls](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36902/26446) on the moon.  He sneaked the modified head of a Wilson 6-iron golf club on board in a sock, and attached it to the handle of a lunar sample scoop.  After hitting two balls, he returned the club head in his spacesuit.  The original is on display at the [USGA Golf Museum](https://www.usga.org/content/usga/home-page/articles/2019/02/three-things-alan-shepard-moon-club.html), and a replica is at the [Smithsonian Air and Space Museum](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/head-golf-club-apollo-14-replica/nasm_A19751468000).

Given that the [Smithsonian usually gets priority](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43523/26446) over space artifacts, **why did they get the copy in this case?**

As usual, please support your answer with sources, rather than speculating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claire Brown, communications director of the Smithsonian Air and Space Museum, was asked [the same question.](https://www.universetoday.com/106544/moonwalkers-golf-club-now-hanging-out-in-new-jersey-museum/)

> “The reason that it’s not in this museum was that it was personal
> property of Alan Shepherd. In other words, he took it to space, he
> brought it back, it was still his personal property he donated it and
> it was his. That’s the reason,” said Claire Brown, the Smithsonian
> National Air and Space Museum’s communications director.
>
> “Things were a little different back then. You could take a certain
> amount of personal property. There are different rules now, but at the
> time that he did it, he was able to bring his own personal club.”

At first glance, it seems a bit odd that the club could be considered "personal property" since the shaft was actually [a contingency sample extension handle.](https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/apollo-to-the-moon/online/later-missions/apollo-14.cfm) But as Shepard explained, ["That [contingency sample extension handle] was already up there to be thrown away."](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/147555main_oral_hist.pdf)

In 1972, Bing Crosby — [who had played golf with Shepard, and happened to be a board member of the USGA Golf Museum](https://www.space.com/apollo-14-moon-landing-golf-shot-analysis) — wrote Shepard asking if he would be willing to donate the club. He agreed, and he presented it to the museum in 1974.